# Android libraries stopped working after the latest updates

Tags: java, android

I recently updated android studio and it's plugins, and all was working properly. But suddenly this happened and i can see how to solve. The app runs, but there are some unexpected behaviours. Tried to sync gradle, uninstall and reinstall the updates and nothing seems to work.

Activity.java for example
[image: Activity.java for example]

Comment: add androidx in your project. Now each library is on androidx

Comment: @ahmadbajwa tried but didn't work..

Comment: Brother, first you need to add androidX

Answer (score 0):

just remove your imports and make sure that they are importing from androidX

or enable auto-import from android studio setting and let it import it for you.[image]